# Is there a way to check if a path is absolute in jinja2?

Tags: python, jinja2, python-sphinx

In the pydata-sphinx-theme we need to check if a path is absolute or not before adding it to the template. Currently we use the following:

```
{% set image_light = image_light if image_light.startswith("http") else pathto('_static/' + image_light, 1) %}
```

It's working but fails to capture local files and many other absolute configurations. Is there a more elegant way to perform this check ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks [@klas Š.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9288580/klas-%C5%A0)for the guidances.

for anyone coming here I did add:

```py
from urllib.parse import urlparse

# The registration function
def setup_is_absolute(app, pagename, templatename, context, doctree):
    def is_absolute(link):
        return bool(urlparse(link).netloc) or link.startswith("/")
    context['is_absolute'] = is_absolute


 # Your extension's setup function
 def setup(app):
     app.connect("html-page-context", setup_is_absolute)
```

and in my template:

```
{{ is_absolute(logo) }}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would consider implementing this logic in Python proper, and bundle it as a [custom template function](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/development/theming.html#defining-custom-template-functions).  This way it'd be much easier to implement, debug and test.